# Google Cloud Platform, Deployment Manager Project, changing the VM instance

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform

We have used the Deployment Manager to create a website from the Wordpress (click to deploy) LAMP server. We have have since recreated the VM instance a few times and also connected another VM instance using nginx as the load balancer/SSL cert.

We have the subdomain resolving to the correct IP and the website is being seen in the web browser. We are getting some errors and think it's the following issue that's causing it. The Deployment for the Project is no longer pointing to any Site Address or Admin URL. I need help knowing how to change which VM instance the Deployment is pointing too. I've read and see the VM name that is in the Manifest. Just need to know how to change the Manifest

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are talking about this [solution](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress) that is available in Cloud Marketplace.
If after the deployment finished, you replaced something manually without [updating](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager/deployments/update) the deployment, then it can be difficult to make changes through the same deployment.

Otherwise, you can make changes on the configuration as indicated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#make_changes_to_your_configuration).